# Is this database normalized enough?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, normalization

I was wondering if you guys could look at this database design and tell me if it normalized to the best it can be. Likewise, if you see any problems or improvements.

[image]

The database is essentially has one to many relationship and is made for households entering into an assistive living program. Each year we have them complete the same form to see if any changes have occurred and analyze the data.

Head of household: Information that I do not believe will be changing. Unique to the social provided.

Contact & Address: I separated address from contact because people that enter this program are required to be living in selected homes. Likewise, people do not stay in this program forever. So it isn't uncommon for us to see different households living in the same address over a period of time.

Income: basically analyzing what they had at the beginning and what they developed over time. So unearned_entry and earned_entry would be consistent but earned and unearned will be fluctuating from each form.

Household_information: for veteran status and disabilities status, although unlikely, can still change. In regards to these two attributes, it's either yes or no (either you have someone disabled in your household or you don't). For the household size and minors, this could be potentially different since relatives may join the household, or children become adults, etc.

Program Information: attributes about each form basically. Intake date - will stay consistent (when they entered the program). Transaction type ( will either be entry, update, or close). Exit date ( will be null until transaction type is close. ).

Comment: Normalization is about getting rid of problematic functional & join dependencies and cannot be done without knowing all dependencies. Please give a reference about normalization that you are trying to follow.

Comment: Your question does not make clear exactly when a row of values should or should not be put into each table. Eg you have many income rows for a given head and many intakes for them but you don't connect any particular income with a particular intake. It seems likely that some of these tables should be combined. Please tell us for each table what a row of values for each column states when in it by giving a sentence template parameterized by column names. Eg "household HOUSEHOLD_ID is headed by SSN and VETERANS_PRESENT is whether there are veterans presents and ...".

Comment: You talk unclearly about "change" and "over a period of time" and "developed over time" and "fluctuating from each form" and "potentially different" and "stay consistent" (?)  and "transaction type" (?). But you do not make clear exactly what info is in the database at any given time (about the past and present). Please do so by means of appropriate sentence templates (*predicates*) per my last comment.